# How to run React/Node Micro Front Ends and Micro Back end Services Docker images on Linux Server?

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile, microservices, podman

I have React,Express and Node stack  micro apps. There are 4 back end services in node and 9 micro-front-end in React. I created a Dockerfile and build Docker Images for all the front and back ends.

I try run all the container images at the same time but had no space left on device after the 4th micro app.

What is the other ways around?

```
`podman run -itd -name micro-frontEnd1-conatiner 8011:8011 localregistry.com/myservices:frontEnd1-Imagetag
podman run -itd -name micro-frontEnd2-conatiner 8012:8012 localregistry.com/myservices:frontEnd2-Imagetag

.......
.......
podman run -itd -name micro-frontEnd9-conatiner 8019:8019 localregistry.com/myservices:frontEnd9-Imagetag

===
podman run -itd -name micro-backEnd1-conatiner 8021:8021 localregistry.com/myservices:backEnd1-Imagetag

.....
.....
podman run -itd -name micro-backEnd4-conatiner 8024:8024 localregistry.com/myservices:backEnd4-Imagetag`
```

Comment: What do you mean you have no space left on device? Are you talking about storage or RAM? Are you running into an error?

Comment: while running  the Docker  image container  on RedHat8 , It was unable to create or run a new container . It pointed to usr/src/...  directory  . I don't think it is RAM. I guess a container storage or storage use to load a docker image and run its container.

Answer (score 1):

Every node service installs its own node_modules,

it can get 400MB (with ts) - 1.2GB(nextjs) easily.

You can share node_modules folder via volumes, this [guy explains](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QSxEZ8_BXn4) for docker.

Simply, (for docker-compose.yml)

```yaml
service1:
  volumes:
    - node_modules:/app/node_modules

service2:
  volumes:
    - node_modules:/app/node_modules
```

I'm not sure if it works for yarn + pnpm + npm mixed.

Also you can deploy only development pods.

Comment: thank for the inputs